# Azure build pipeline started failing suddenly (current version of the following service is not supported: GitOdb)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

The error message i'm getting is "current version of the following service is not supported: GitOdb".

Build pipeline is for ASP.NET CORE(v3) API project.

When i click on the error it says "Build not found"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, there is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which affected these services, and it has been resolved now. If you want to know more information, please click here: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/188718946 .

> The issue is now fully mitigated. To mitigate, we stopped updates and
>   upgraded the impacted databases. We recognize the wide impact this had
>   to our customers in this region and will be following up on learnings
>   and improvements to prevent the chance of recurrence. We apologize for
>   the impact this caused.

In this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1041389/git-repos-in-azure-devops-are-empty.html), many users encountered the same problem (starting a build pipeline immediately fails with TF400860: The current version of the following service is not supported: GitOdb. Version: 1700, MinVersion: 1700),  which has now been fixed.